# Using threads correctly has stumped me

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to learn how to use threads. I have made an example using the API and documents  Trying to make it as simple as possible . A form 2 buttons and a progress-bar to update I'm unable to get it to work from the API example. First My basic Form then the class that supposed to run the thread properly. When I click a button it freezes the GUI and doesn't update the progress bar, some mentioned I'm block the GUI thread... which confused me. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
package mythreadtry;

/**
 *
 * @author brett
 */
public class MyThreadMainGui extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /**
     * Creates new form MyThreadMainGui
     */
    public MyThreadMainGui(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(208, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(210, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        MyThreadTry mmt = new MyThreadTry();
        mmt.doit(null);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         MyThreadTry mmt = new MyThreadTry();
        mmt.doit(null);
    }                                        
//    
    public void updateProgress(int newValue){
        jProgressBar1.setValue(newValue);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyThreadMainGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyThreadMainGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyThreadMainGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyThreadMainGui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyThreadMainGui dialog = new MyThreadMainGui(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Next is my attempt at a thread.. which is simple I hope. I included the whole form so you guys can tell how im trying to call the class.

```
package mythreadtry;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author brett
 */
public class MyThreadTry implements Runnable{
 long minPrime;
  volatile Thread p =  new Thread();
  volatile boolean threadSuspended;
         MyThreadTry() {
             int times = 100000; 
             for(int i = 0; i <= times; i++ ){
                 this.minPrime = i;
                 System.out.println(this.minPrime);
                 MyThreadMainGui myg = new MyThreadMainGui(null, threadSuspended);
                 myg.updateProgress((int)this.minPrime);
             }

         }
     public void doit(String[] args) {
       p.start();

    }
         public void run() {
            Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
            threadSuspended = true;
        while (p == thisThread) {
            try {
                p.sleep(500);

                synchronized(this) {
                    while (threadSuspended && p==thisThread)
                        wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
            }
        }
    }
public synchronized void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        e.consume();

        threadSuspended = !threadSuspended;

        if (!threadSuspended)
            notify();
    }
    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.p = null;
        notify();
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


}
```

Comment: Swing is a single threaded environment AND is not thread safe, you should never create or modify the UI from outside of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: Could you please elaborate some more im really lost on how to do this i need some basic instruction

Comment: You should read up on [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: You also seem to misunderstand how Thread objects work. `while (p == thisThread) {`? `p.sleep`? And you created your Thread without overriding its run method or passing it a Runnable, so it does nothing when started (apart from immediately exiting).

Comment: To be specific, `while (p == thisThread)` can never be false, and is therefore both pointless and meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I click a button it freezes the GUI and doesn't update the progress bar

When you push one of your buttons, you create an instance of `MyThreadTry`

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    MyThreadTry mmt = new MyThreadTry();
    mmt.doit(null);
}
```

The constructor of `MyThreadTry` then loops 100, 000 times, creating 100, 000 instances of `MyThreadMainGUI`

```
MyThreadTry() {
     int times = 100000; 
     for(int i = 0; i <= times; i++ ){
         this.minPrime = i;
         System.out.println(this.minPrime);
         MyThreadMainGui myg = new MyThreadMainGui(null, threadSuspended);
         myg.updateProgress((int)this.minPrime);
     }
 }
```

All within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  The EDT is responsible for processing the Event Queue, which includes, amongst other things, paint events.

This means that until this method actually finishes, nothing can be updated.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

When the constructor "finally" returns, you call `doit`, which calls `p.start`.  But since you've not overridden `p`'s `run` method nor supplied it a `Runnable`, it does nothing...

**Updated with runnable example**

My preferences is to use a `SwingWorker` in these cases, but since we're talking about threads, here's a threaded version instead.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private JButton button;

        private Worker worker;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            pb = new JProgressBar();
            button = new JButton("Run");

            add(pb, gbc);
            add(button, gbc);

            pb.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(pb.getValue());
                    if (pb.getValue() >= 100) {
                        button.setText("Run");
                        worker = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            pb.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                }
            });

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (worker == null) {
                        worker = new Worker(pb);
                        Thread t = new Thread(worker);
                        t.start();
                        button.setText("Pause");
                    } else {
                        if (worker.isPaused()) {
                            button.setText("Pause");
                            worker.resume();
                        } else {
                            button.setText("Resume");
                            worker.pause();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class Worker implements Runnable {

        private ReentrantLock pausedLock;
        private Condition pausedCondition;
        private AtomicBoolean paused;

        private JProgressBar pb;

        public Worker(JProgressBar pb) {
            paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
            pausedLock = new ReentrantLock();
            pausedCondition = pausedLock.newCondition();
            this.pb = pb;
        }

        public void pause() {

            paused.set(true);

        }

        public void resume() {

            paused.set(false);
            pausedLock.lock();
            try {
                pausedCondition.signal();
            } finally {
                pausedLock.unlock();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int times = 100_000;
            for (int i = 0; i <= times; i++) {
                checkPauseState();
                updateProgress(Math.round((i / (float) times) * 100f));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }

        }

        protected void checkPauseState() {

            while (paused.get()) {
                pausedLock.lock();
                try {
                    pausedCondition.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                } finally {
                    pausedLock.unlock();
                }
            }

        }

        protected void updateProgress(int progress) {
            if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                pb.setValue(progress);
            } else {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateProgress(progress);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public  boolean isPaused() {
            return paused.get();
        }

    }

}
```

Make sure you make the time to read through [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), especially the section on locks, and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: so how do i fix this, i keep doin cicles im lost

Comment: But since you've not overridden p's run method not supplied it a RunnablezBut since you've not overridden p's run method not supplied it a Runnable I think this is the part im stuck on, can i bother you  for some basic instruction?

Comment: How do i supply a runnable?

Comment: The JavaDocs for [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)) clearly show that you can pass a `Runnable` to the `Thread` via it's constructor.  The JavaDocs for `Thread` also show both use cases, overriding `run` (not recommended) and using a `Runnable`.  If that's not enough, there is also a runnable example.  Make sure you are consulting the documenting listed for more details